# label+dynamic number.text = "" vba

Tags: vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, numbers

I want to write dynamic number for label text. Example:

```
Label1.text = ""
```

i want instead of 1, the dynamic number, no but the error is obtained. 
I this want
example

```
dim number as integer = 34
Label(number).text = ""
```

How to write `true`?

Comment: What you mean by dynamic? Random number?

Comment: no variable number example 
dim number as integer = 13
label&number&.text = "text"

Comment: Sounds like they should bring back control arrays.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using vb.net. loop through all control and match by name.

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If c.GetType Is GetType(Label) And c.Name = "Label" & StrNumber Then
        c.Text = "Text"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Happened ! . Thank you brother.